# How to know client connection status in bottle?

Tags: python, bottle, server-sent-events

I'm testing a Server-sent event website with bottle framework. The problem is that after the client disconnected, the server still keeps sending messages, resulting in broken pipe exception. Is there a way in bottle to know the connection status? Something like IsClientConnected in ASP.NET?

Comment: I think you found it.  It raises an exception.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Yes, it raised an exception, but how could I catch that exception? It's beyond my control because middleware raised it.